# Qt MOC: When default and copy constructor are used?

Tags: c++, qt, moc

I have to add my own type to Qt MetaObject System (register metatype). Due to manual, following requirements have to be met:

- default constructor
- copy constructor
- destructor

My class does not have a sense with default constructor; it will be created only to satisfy QT MOS. However: how, when and why Qt calls default ctor? What happens if my class stores pointers to dynamically created elements : will MOS create copy of such class, and then, it will delete it and free all pointers?

Answer (score 0):

> will MOS create copy of such class, and then, it will delete it and free all pointers?

Yes, when announcing events, they are first copied. This is done this way, in order to simplify sending of events from one to another thread.

> What happens if my class stores pointers to dynamically created elements : will MOS create copy of such class, and then, it will delete it and free all pointers?

That is what a custom copy constructor is for. That is your task to make sure everything is copied fine, and no memory leak (or other problem) is possible.

---

Finally, I found where it talks. It is in [this link](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.1/qtcore/qobject.html#connect) :

> The optional type parameter describes the type of connection to establish. In particular, it determines whether a particular signal is delivered to a slot immediately or queued for delivery at a later time. **If the signal is queued, the parameters must be of types that are known to Qt's meta-object system, because Qt needs to copy the arguments to store them in an event behind the scenes.** If you try to use a queued connection and get the error message