# What benefits does QT get with normalized signature

Tags: c++, qt

I read that QT applies signature normalization process on the signal/slot mechanism. MOC generator basically removes the const reference qualifiers from signals/slots and just pass them by value.

I have a class which generates a big data structure called BIG_DATA so frequently and some other classes need to catch this data structure every time it is emitted.

```
struct BIG_DATA
{
    // very big data
};

class DataGenerator
{
    // some methods which generate BIG_DATA

   signals:
      void data_updated(const BIG_DATA &);
};
```

What i do :

```
connect(&data_generator_object, SIGNAL(data_updated(const BIG_DATA &)), this, SLOT(catch_new_data(const BIG_DATA &)));
```

What QT does :

```
connect(&data_generator_object, SIGNAL(data_updated(BIG_DATA)), this, SLOT(catch_new_data(BIG_DATA)));
```

So, what is the benefit of removing const reference qualifiers here ? What am i going to do with the overhead of copying the whole BIG_DATA to many clients of data_updated signal ?

Seems like the best way is to use a pointer to the generated BIG_DATA object, if QT doesn't attempt to remove the pointer signature too.

Comment: Is `connect` a function declaration or a function call (or a wacky macro that does some of both)?  It looks like a function call.  You don't put parameter types in function calls.  What about `SIGNAL`?

Comment: SIGNAL() and SLOT() are just macros which convert the parameters to a char array. connect() is a function call.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Signature normalization is used only to identify signals and slots. That is, if you want to tell `connect()` which signal or slot to use, you need to pass normalized signature there. But your signal's and slot's signatures remain untouched. If you use direct connection (which is default for single-threaded program), your object will not be copied.

Comment: are you sure direct connections are default for single threaded program?

Comment: @BЈовић [AutoConnection is the default for every program](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.1/qtcore/qt.html#ConnectionType-enum), but in a single-threaded context it will behave exactly as DirectConnection would.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using queued connections, your structure is copied anyway (see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18058022/476681)).

Now, if you use use normalized signals, you can minimize performance hit when you are using connect ([see this](http://marcmutz.wordpress.com/effective-qt/prefer-to-use-normalised-signalslot-signatures/)) :

> Lookup is first attempted with the signature as-is, and only if that fails is QMetaObject::normalizedSignature() called.
>
> That means, when using non-normalised signal/slot signatures, you not only pay for a strcpy(), but also for a doomed-to-fail first lookup attempt. Sure, connects are usually done during startup, and a profiler won’t show you, but using non-normalised signatures is hereby firmly put into the realm of premature pessimisation.

However, the performance hit is only when using connect, not when sending signals. And the connections are made usually only once. Therefore I wouldn't worry too much.

In order to avoid the structure copy, use references.